# How do I get cypher graph algorithm result nodes and their neighbors in one query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph loaded into neo4j v3.4.6 and I would like to compute the centrality of the nodes, grabbing the top `N` entries along with their neighbors and the relationships between them. I would like to do this as a *single* cypher query. Sounds simple enough but I'm quite new to the Cypher query language and not adapting quickly to its non-SQL-ness. I am working with a system I cannot modify, so I am suck with neo4j v3.4.6. The system also has an older version of `apoc` library that is lacking the `apoc.neighbors` procedure (not sure if that would be useful if I had it, but it sounds useful).

Here are the two best examples of what I have tried thus far. Both require multiple queries. I will use `N=10`:

1. Effectively what I want but might get extra "most central" nodes (and their neighbors) if there are ties for the `N`th highest centrality score.

```
// Compute the centrality scores and write them back to the graph:
CALL algo.betweenness(
  null, // nodeLabel; null for all nodes
  null, // edgeLabel; null for all edges
  {
    direction: 'both',
    write: true,
    writeProperty: "centrality"
  }
)
```

```
// Get the top N=10 centrality scores, take note of the
// smallest value in this list:
MATCH (n)
RETURN n.centrality
ORDER BY n.centrality DESC
LIMIT 10
```

```
// Match the paths where the centrality of the first node
// is `>=` the threshold from the previous query.
// Let's assume that threshold was `100`
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WHERE n.centrality >= 100
RETURN n, r, m
```

2. Not what I want. It stops after `N` relationships/edges -- which might not exhaust the neighborhood of even the 1st most central node in my graph, let alone the top `N` central nodes -- rather than "all relationships starting with the top `N` central nodes".

```
// Compute the centrality scores and write them back to the graph:
// Same as above
CALL algo.betweenness(
  null, // nodeLabel; null for all nodes
  null, // edgeLabel; null for all edges
  {
    direction: 'both',
    write: true,
    writeProperty: "centrality"
  }
)
```

```
// Grab the first `N` single-hop paths `(n)-[r]-(m)` sorted by `n.centratlity`
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
RETURN n, r, m
ORDER BY n.centrality DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

With some more research I found a solution. Uses `.stream` instead of writing centrality score back to the graph, and a `WITH` `...` `ORDER BY` `...` `LIMIT` clause to do the in-place ordering and filtering. Here is my query:

```
CALL algo.betweenness.stream(
  null, // nodeLabel; null for all nodes
  null, // edgeLabel; null for all edges
  {
    direction: "both"
  }
)
YIELD nodeId, centrality
// Grab the top N=10 results
WITH nodeId, centrality
  ORDER BY centrality DESC
  LIMIT 10
// Extend results to include neighborhood
MATCH (n)
  WHERE id(n) = nodeId
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
  WHERE id(n) = nodeId
RETURN n, r, m
```